# Call to undefined function odbc_connect() message while connecting SAP HANA database

Tags: php, odbc, hana

I used `odbc_connect()` in my PHP page to connect to the HANA database. It works fine when I run it locally.

I upload the same PHP page into the server and I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

The code:

```
$connect = odbc_connect("Team6DataSource", "TEAM6", "Password1", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

Team6DataSource = datasource name.

ip address = 54.217.234.218

Can any one please help me?
Thanks

Comment: do you check php.ini file ?

Comment: sounds like you need to define odbc_connect :\

Comment: if it is running on the remote server then how could i change it?

Comment: please read this:http://www.clearfoundation.com/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,232/catid,17/func,view/id,12665/

Comment: how can i define odbc_connect? :)

Comment: do you connect in PHP while you can connect by using odbc_connect function

Comment: Hi VIVEK-MDU the post you sent me it says it is missing include file or something. If that so then how come it is working perfect while i am running locally?

Comment: Hi @ron...Read this article how to connect ODBC for live database http://www.phphelp.com/tutorial/using-myodbc-to-connect-to-a-remote-database.html and you can call simple function odbc_connect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just go through in google get [this instruction](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html) this is really helpful for you.

1. [Download the SQL Server ODBC driver for your PHP client

   platform.](http://www.easysoft.com/cgi-bin/account/login.cgi) (Registration required.) If the SQL Server ODBC driver
   is not currently available for your platform, check the list of
   [ODBC-ODBC Bridge Client platforms](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/index.html#platforms). The ODBC-ODBC Bridge is an
   alternative SQL Server solution from Easysoft, which you can
   download    from this site.
2. Install and license the SQL Server ODBC driver on the machine where
   PHP is installed. For installation instructions, see the ODBC driver
   documentation. Refer to the documentation to see which environment
   variables you need to set **`(LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBPATH, LD_RUN_PATH,
   SHLIB_PATH depending on the driver, platform and linker).`**
3. Create an ODBC data source in `/etc/odbc.ini` that connects to the
   `SQL Server database` you want to access from PHP. For example, this
   SQL Server ODBC data source connects to a SQL Server Express instance
   that serves the Northwind database:

   - Use isql to test the new data source. For example:
     **`cd /usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC/bin`**

   ./isql -v MSSQL-PHP

> ```
> [MSSQL-PHP]
> Driver                  = Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server
> Server                  = my_machine\SQLEXPRESS
> User                    = my_domain\my_user
> Password                = my_password
> ```

Please copy and paste this script and execute this

```
<?
/*
PHP MSSQL Example

Replace data_source_name with the name of your data source.
Replace database_username and database_password
with the SQL Server database username and password.
*/
$data_source='data_source_name';
$user='database_username';
$password='database_password';

// Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
$conn=odbc_connect($data_source,$user,$password);
if (!$conn){
    if (phpversion() < '4.0'){
      exit("Connection Failed: . $php_errormsg" );
    }
    else{
      exit("Connection Failed:" . odbc_errormsg() );
    }
}

// This query generates a result set with one record in it.
$sql="SELECT 1 AS test_col";

# Execute the statement.
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

// Fetch and display the result set value.
if (!$rs){
    exit("Error in SQL");
}
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
    $col1=odbc_result($rs, "test_col");
    echo "$col1\n";
}

// Disconnect the database from the database handle.
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

1. Replace `data_source_name, database_username and database_password`
   with your SQL Server ODBC data source, login name and password.
2. To run the script under Apache, save the file below your Apache web
   server’s document root directory`. For example,
   /var/www/apache2-default/php-mssql-connection.phtml. Then view the
   file in a web browser:`

   ```
   http://localhost/php-mssql-connection.phtml
   ```
3. If your web browser is not running on the same machine as the web
   server, replace localhost with the web server’s host name or IP
   address.
4. To run the script from the command line, save the file.

   For example,
       /tmp/php-mssql-connection.php. Then run $ php
       /tmp/php-mssql-connection.php.

### further more Details Refer this [LINK](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20098), copy the `.dll` to PHP folder and in the `php.ini` file add:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

windows
I downloaded apache 2.4 x64 zip; copied to: D:\Apache24-devel
https://www.apachelounge.com/download/
I downloaded php 8.3 threadsafe x64 zip; copied to D:\php-8-ts

Mind, in paths below I use "/..." without drive letter "D:" because I installed/extracted Apache and PHP on the same drive letter "D:".

In Apache conf/httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php_module "/php-8-ts/php8apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

<FilesMatch \.(php$|php3)>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "/php-8-ts/"
```

In php-8-ts/php.ini:

```
extension=odbc
extension_dir = "D:/php-8-ts/ext"
```

For configuration check (**odbc**) create:
D:/Apache24-devel/htdocs/dirX/phpinfo.php:

```
<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
?>
```

Check out:

```
> D:
> cd D:\Apache24-devel
> bin\httpd.exe
```

http://localhost/dirX/phpinfo.php