# PHP 7.0 ODBC-Driver for Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, odbc, php-7

I upgraded my PHP 5.6.30 (https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html) to PHP 7.0 (https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer)

Everything worked fine so far and it reduces the loading time from my Page from 1,2 seconds to ~300 ms, when I use a MySQL-Database. But now I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL-Database with the following simple script, that worked fine with my old installation (PHP 5.6):

```
<?php
    //Use the machine name and instance if multiple instances are used
    $server = 'Server-Adress';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    //Define Port
    $port='Port=1433';
    $database = 'Databasename';

    $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;$port;DATABASE=$database";
    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connection established.";
    } else{
        die("Connection could not be established.");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM st3_200 WHERE identifier = 1";

    $result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
    // Get Data From Result
      while ($data[] = odbc_fetch_array($result));

      // Free Result
      odbc_free_result($result);

      // Close Connection
      odbc_close($conn);

      // Show data
      print_r($data);

?>
```

But now I got an error in my logs that says:

> [Thu Dec 10 11:55:26.629956 2015] [:error] [pid 260:tid 968] [client
>   ::1:63003] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined
>   function odbc_connect() in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0-0\apache2\htdocs\test\query.php:11\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0-0\apache2\htdocs\test\query.php on
>   line 11

First I thought, that my php.ini has a missing extension, so I enabled "extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll"

the difference from the php.ini in the 5.6 version is there is the extension:
"extension=php_mssql.dll" enabled. But I can't find them in the new PHP 7.0.ini

So my intension is there is no existing driver for odbc and PHP 7 yet?
I found some driver for Linux here:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/php7-odbc/

But I need something for my Windows environment.

Does anyone had the same issue and has already fixed it?

Thank und Greeting
Domi

Comment: Your code is using the ODBC extension but you're trying to load two unrelated extensions (a PDO driver and the good old MSSQL extension).

Comment: `php_pdo_odbc.dll` isn't the odbc extension, it's the ODBC driver for PDO. You want `php_odbc.dll`

Answer (score 10):

Take a look in your php.ini, the string

```
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

seems to be missing in new installations, at least i had to add it manually in my new XAMPP installation (7.0.1)
and accidently just activated the pdo_odbc.dll

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>PHP7</kbd> has a few modules disabled by default that were previously enabled in <kbd>PHP5</kbd>.

It's an easy fix though since the extension should already exist in the `\ext\` folder that came with <kbd>PHP7</kbd>. You just need to modify your `php.ini` file to include the line:

```
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

*The line above is **not** already present and commented out; you actually need to add it!*

PHP looks for the `php.ini` file in `C:\Windows\` but it may also be located elsewhere on your machine. So check both `C:\Windows\` and `C:\php\` or where ever else you may have installed PHP.

After making the change you can check the results from the command line like this:

```
C:\php\php.exe -m
```

or (after restarting the web server / machine) from a `.phtml` file like this:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

That will output a list of enabled modules which should now include <kbd>odbc</kbd>; if not, then you may have modified the wrong `php.ini` file (keep looking) or forgot to restart the web server / machine.

---

#### Tips:

If you have a non-standard installation, you can use an absolute path like this:

```
extension=C:\php7x64\ext\php_odbc.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

extension=php_mssql.dll (or extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll if you get it from Microsoft Drivers for PHP), is your problem: the Microsoft SQL driver for PHP 7 is not yet ready, the latest ETA is late January for the beta.

It looks like the cause of the delay is the intention to include SQL 2016 in that driver so you can migrate easier in the future.

**UPDATE (2016/02/12):**

As stated [here](https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/issues/58) (meet-bhagdev reply), there is an "early technical preview" of the PHP sqlsrv driver for Windows available on [github](https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.0.0).

Answer (score 2):

Open your php.ini file and uncomment or add the following lines:

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"  ;<- your PHP path
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

Reset Internet Information Services:
On command prompt with admin rights type:

```
iisreset
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Adrian B`s which mentions the official driver, you can also check https://github.com/thomsonreuters/msphpsql
This is an unofficial port. However there are limitations for the time being.

1. Supports only sqlsrv ODBC but not PDO
2. Doesn`t support ZTS, only NTS
3. Supports only x86
4. It supports a subset of ODBC functions , you can see the list on the page.

Answer (score 1):

We need x86 driver from Microsoft.
http://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/download/details.aspx?id=13255
*Sorry, 'ja-jp' is mine.  Please select your country.  There are 2 drivers, one is 32bit, but we need 64bit(x86) version.
Then we could set "ODBC data source (64bit)". It appears on the window.
Last, check your web. Maybe it works.
Mar. 29th. 2016  Naio

Answer (score 0):

I guess you was right, you need **download the SQL Server ODBC driver for your PHP client platform and OS**.
Here is the link for the similar issue: [Call to undefined function odbc_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859989/call-to-undefined-function-odbc-connect-message-while-connecting-sap-hana-data)

also you can try to install this connector for MySQL (if you use MySQL): [Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

or if you use MSSQL: [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old. But I've come across the same issue recently ...

@Naio is right : there are indeed different versions of ODBC drivers, based on the architecture (32bits or 64bits). The driver that PHP uses depends on its own version.

In other words, if you are using a 32bits ODBC environement, make sure to use a 32bits version of PHP ...

My guess is that, by switching from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0 you also switched from a 32bits version to a 64bits version.