# How to connect to MS SQLSever from ubuntu using PHP 7

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, php-7

I am trying to connect to Microsoft sqlserver from ubuntu using PHP 7, but i am getting this error,

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

FYI: there is no line called ;extension=php_mssql.dll in php.ini to remove the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.0 ODBC-Driver for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200997/php-7-0-odbc-driver-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

you are using linux , so you won't find the line 
`extension=php_mssql.dll`

it perhaps be `extension=php_mssql.so` ,

the php extensions in ubuntu is suffixed by `.so`

and for connecting to mssql server from php
you have to take a look at [PDO MSSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

> Example #1 PDO_DBLIB DSN examples
>
> The following examples show a PDO_DBLIB DSN for connecting to
>   Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases:
>
> mssql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
>
> sybase:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
>
> dblib:host=localhost;dbname=testdb

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the same as  [PHP7 can't connect to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051795/php7-cant-connect-to-mysql)

PHP7 no longer supports the *mysql* interfaces.  You will need to start using mysqli or PDO

Comment: this does not apply please ignore this