# ODBC connection on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, odbc

I am trying to make a localhosted WordPress site use the ODBC connections I use for business analytics.

I made a plugin and am trying to reference the functions in *shortcode (because this is the only way I know to do this)*.

Below is my code:

```
$dsn = '****';
$user = '****';
$pw = '****';
$connect = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pw);
if ($connect == true){
    echo '<br> connected <br>';
} else{
    echo '<br> not connected <br>';
}
```

From what I understand this should be testing to see if the connection is open and it gives me an error (posted below). My big question is if I need to install an ODBC driver on the site to make it able to perform the connection.

If so, where do I find this?

I use four MS SQL servers on the domain and would also like to be able to work with access and excel.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()
>   in
>   C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\HPM-custom\HPM.php:54

```
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(326):HPM_API_E2('', '', 'HPM_API_E2')     
#1 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) 
#2 C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(223):preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(HPM_AP...','do_shortcode_ta...','[HPM_API_E2]\n[H...') 
#3 C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\plugin.php(235):do_shortcode('[HPM_API_E2]\n[H...') 
#4 C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\post-template.php(240):apply_filters('the_content', '[HPM_API_E2]\n[H...') 
#5 C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\generatepress\content-page.php(24):the_content() 
#6 C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\template.php(574):require('C:\\Bitnami\\word...') 
#7 C:\Bitnam in C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.5.3-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\HPM-custom\HPM.php on line 54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$connect` will never be true. This is because `odbc_connect()` does not return a boolean when it succeeds. It returns a `connection ID`instead.

If the connection fails it will return an error or `false`, so it will end up in the `else`. If it succeeds it contains an `ID` and should evaluate to `true`.

```
if ($connect){
  echo '<br> connected <br>';
} else{
  echo '<br> not connected <br>';
}
```

Edit:

You've just added the error message you're getting. That error means the `function` is not available, and that will most likely be caused by the missing `ODBC drivers` for your php client. Someone else made this post on how to install this:

[Call to undefined function odbc_connect() message while connecting SAP Hana database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859989/call-to-undefined-function-odbc-connect-message-while-connecting-sap-hana-data)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that specifically clears up what I don't know. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! Could you be so kind to update my answer if it was helpfull? :)